How can I format the number of authors differently in a LaTeX template based on how many authors are entered in the YAML of a quarto book?
I have created a Quarto LaTeX template for my students who write their papers in groups. In this latex-template.tex, it is defined how the authors are to be listed sequentially with their email addresses and student ID numbers. With 4 people, it still works quite well. With 5 people, the title page is quite messed up (in the original, there's also the module, details about the semester, and the instructor included). Is it somehow possible to introduce a condition in the YAML of index.qmd or in the latex-template.tex so that an even number of people are displayed in two columns, and for an odd number of people, the last one is centered and all are a bit smaller and closer together?
I have already tried to see if something like $if(author.count == 5)$ works, but I only encountered resistance.
Reprex
index.qmd
---
title: 'Multiauthors'

author:
- given-names: Lena
  surname: Günther
  Email: lena.guenther@uzh.ch
  MatrikelNr: 21-234-34
- given-names: Urs
  surname: Borner
  Email: urs.borner@uzh.ch
  MatrikelNr: 21-234-35
- given-names: Klausi
  surname: Manteufel
  Email: klausi.manteufel@uzh.ch
  MatrikelNr: 21-234-37
- given-names: Annelies Gudrun
  surname: Krüger
  Email: annelies.kruger@uzh.ch
  MatrikelNr: 21-234-38
- given-names: Bodobert
  surname: Schimmelpfennig
  Email: annelies.kruger@uzh.ch
  MatrikelNr: 20-264-58

  chapters:
    -  index.qmd

format:
  pdf:
    template: latex-template.tex
---

latex-template.tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}



$if(title)$
{\sffamily \Huge \bf $title$} \\[1ex]
$endif$

\begin{multicols}{2}
    $for(author)$\raggedright \Large $author.surname$, $author.given-names$ \\*[1ex]
    \normalsize $author.Email$\\*
    Matrikelnummer: $author.MatrikelNr$ $sep$\\[1cm]
    $endfor$
\end{multicols}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}

